# building a carrousel with Images from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal, dom-manipulation

To practise with vainilla JS, i want to bulding a carrousel / slider, with images imported from a JSON object, and when I click on "next" , it should show different images imported from the Json Object
For the carrousel i am using Bootstrap in my HTML file , and I loop through the object to extract the images and create and append the img element.

The part of the bootstrap Modal in HTML where i create the Img element  :

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="sliderImg">
      <!-- Here i append a : <div class="item active" id="slider-active">
       <!-- here I append an <img src=''> with the URL from the JSON -->
             <div class="carousel-caption">
                   ...
             </div>
     </div>
```

And in my JS file i created the following function :

```
function createCards(data) {
    let cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardContainer');
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {   
        //MODAL SLIDER       
        aInfoButtonLeft.onclick = function () {
            console.log('left btn clicked')

            let divSliderActive = document.getElementById('sliderImg')
            let imgSliderActive = document.createElement('img');
            imgSliderActive.setAttribute('src', data[i]['Image Gallery'][i]['src']);
            imgSliderActive.append(divSliderActive);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when i click the aInfoButtonLeft, i get an error from bootstrap

```
.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
    at c.slide (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at c.next (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2)
```

So I am not sure if my approach isn´t right (no easy/possible to insert the elements from JS having the structure in HTML) , or if my code is bad (98% chances) , or both.

Ps: the JS function is way longer, since I also generate some Cards with info and two buttons, one of them is the once used to trigger the slider.
For the HTML part, the rest of the modal structure is copied from bootstrap.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just populate the whole carousel from the JSON at the start?

Comment: you mean generate all the elements from JS? 
I guess i did not do it because it was gonna be many lines of code to create the elements and the classes and values , and the function would be way bigger (now is like 250 lines to generate a table in one html, and the cards in this one)
Also, I am not sure if that would make a difference  to my current issue

Comment: Its just a few lines of code to populate the entire slideshow. And it would make the carousel code cleaner. And it would allow you to preload images if you wanted. And it would allow you to use css transitions more effectively. However, for a simple click-to-see-a-new-image setup, you could populate it one at a time. Note that the error you're getting doesn't correspond with the code you're posting (no mention of offsetWidth anywhere in your code)

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

as you might have imagined (in case it wasn´t that obvious from my code :D ), i am pretty new at this. Could you give me a hint about how to do that?

Or would be enought just creating all the elements with JS, keeping the same structure i already have in HTML? (